# TypeOrm Tree solution for migrations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I'm trying to create Tree structure in TypeORM, and now I'm trying to add migration file

Here is my Tree Structure:

```
import {
    Entity,
    Column,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    OneToMany,
    CreateDateColumn,
    Tree,
    TreeChildren,
    TreeParent,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity('tree')
@Tree('materialized-path')
export class Tree {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id', type: 'integer' })
    id: number;


    @Column()
    name: string;


    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
    createdAt: string;

    @TreeChildren()
    children: AssetType[];

    @TreeParent()
    parent: AssetType;

}
```

My Question is How should now I create migration file for this Tree that is imported from TypeORM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used TypeORM Cli to generate migration

Used command: typeorm migration:generate like described here:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md#generating-migrations

It created following migration:

```
await queryRunner.query(
    `CREATE TABLE
        "table_name"
        (
            "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
            "name" character varying NOT NULL
            "mpath" character varying DEFAULT '',
            "parentId" integer,
            CONSTRAINT "PK_9b5ee2748943131ed9d9831e8c9" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
        )`,
    undefined
);
await queryRunner.query(
    `ALTER TABLE
        "table_name"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_9da62161e3c7bc51981ff7fa1da"
    FOREIGN KEY ("parentId") REFERENCES "table_name"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
    undefined
);
```